# Link to a build in GitHub Actions like the Jenkins PR Builder plugin

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that runs when a PR is opened and when any further commits are pushed to the PR's branch.

I used the [Jenkins PR builder plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/) previously. There, it was possible to post a link to the PR associated with the PR check -- the "Details" link could be defined from within the Jenkins job. Example:
[image: Jenking PR builder in GitHub]

Is there a way to post a similar (arbitrary) link from a GitHub Action workflow that will display next to the PR check?

EDIT: A couple of alternatives I found:

- a way to output arbitrary links/info to the run's summary page: https://github.com/chromaui/chromatic-cli/issues/699#issuecomment-1363698969
- the workflow could add a comment to the PR: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-pr-comment

But I would like to post a link that would be clickable from the PR and would be located right next to the check at the bottom of the PR. Also, the Jenkins PR builder allows clicking on each commit where the check ran and clicking on the Details link from there as well -- that would be awesome.

Comment: Are those links automatically created the same way, when running the github actions workflow runs on a PR? As you can see on this [example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1078012/81287548-dd270600-905a-11ea-8c89-3a16982223eb.png), the `Details` link is present for each run triggered by the PR.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I don't know how GitHub Actions workflows generate those links. I do know that the Jenkins PR builder can set that link to any arbitrary URL, and that it's user-configurable.

Comment: Those links are indeed generated automatically by GitHub. After a few researches here I couldn't find a way to edit them. However, you could eventually do as you said and generate a comment on the PR with a customized clickable link.